# Python WebScraper with Logins, but no form

Tags: python, web-scraping, squarespace

I am trying to run a webscraper on the back end of my Squarespace website. I tried the code below, but it looks like the log in page doesn't have a form. Is that possible? If so, how can I log in to Squarespace?

My goal is to scrape the Orders I have on the Commerce --> Inventory page.

It would mean a lot if someone could help me out with this. Thank you in advanced!

```
    import mechanize
    import http.cookiejar as cookielib
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import html2text

    # Browser
    br = mechanize.Browser()

    # Cookie Jar
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    # Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

    # The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
    br.open('https://login.squarespace.com/')

    # View available forms
    for f in br.forms():
        print (f)
```

Comment: You are correct that the login page does not contain any `<form>` elements; it simply contains input fields within divs. So, if a function looks for form elements, it will not detect any on that page. Also, if your plan supports it, you may consider using the Commerce API instead ( https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis) . With it, you can "Retrieve product variant stock levels".

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. The APIs are part of the advanced plan which i don't have

Comment: I'm wondering how I can log in without forms?

Comment: There may be an easier way to do this, in general, without the APIs. Are you simply trying to obtain current inventory levels? Also, how many products do you have roughly?